# Proving $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K(x)K\left ( \sqrt{2} \sqrt{(1-x^2)/(2-x^2)} \right ) }{2-x^2}\text{d}x =\frac{\pi^3}{8\sqrt{2} } {}_6F_5(...)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, elliptic-integrals

I encountered an integral identity:

> $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K(x)K\left ( \sqrt{2} 
> \sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{2-x^2} }  \right ) }{2-x^2}\,dx
> =\frac{\pi^3}{8\sqrt{2}} 
> {}_6F_5\left ( \frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},
> \frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4};
> \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1,1,1;1   \right ).$$
> Where $K(x)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} 
> \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2t^2} }\text{d}t$ and ${}_6F_5$ is the *Generalized Hypergeometric function*.\

Here is my attempt:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K(x)K\left ( \sqrt{2} 
\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{2-x^2} }  \right ) }{2-x^2}\text{d}x\\ \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{K(\sqrt{x} )K\left ( \sqrt{2} 
\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{2-x}}\right) }{\sqrt{x} (2-x)}\text{d}x\\ \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{K(\sqrt{1-x} )K\left ( \sqrt{2} 
\sqrt{\frac{x}{1+x} }  \right ) }{\sqrt{1-x}(1+x) }\text{d}x\\ \\
&=\;...
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Thanks to the user who answered this question. I had found these closed-forms:
$$\int_{0}^{1} 
\frac{K^2\left ( \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2} }
\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{2-x^2} }   }  \right ) 
K(\sqrt{1-x^2} )}{2-x^2}\text{d}x
=
\frac{\pi ^{7/2} \,\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \, _8F_7\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4};\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1,1,1;1\right)}{32 \sqrt{2}\, \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}+\frac{\pi ^{7/2} \,\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right) \, _8F_7\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4};1,1,1,\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};1\right)}{128 \sqrt{2} \,\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}$$
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_4\left ( \frac{x}{\sqrt{2-x^2} }  \right )
K(\sqrt{1-x^2}) }{2-x^2}\text{d}x
=\frac{\pi}{4 \sqrt{2}}\, _7F_6\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4};1\right)
+\frac{1}{243 \sqrt{2}}\, _7F_6\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},1,1,1;\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4},\frac{7}{4},\frac{7}{4},\frac{7}{4},\frac{7}{4};1\right)
+\frac{\pi ^{3/2} \,\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}{64 \sqrt{2} \,\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)} \, _6F_5\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4};\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};1\right)
+\frac{\pi ^{3/2} \, \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}{16384 \sqrt{2}\,\Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}\, _7F_6\left(1,1,1,1,1,\frac{5}{4},\frac{5}{4};\frac{3}{2},2,2,2,2,2;1\right)$$

Comment: A lead: $$K(z)K(Z)=\frac{\pi^2}{4}{_2F_1}\left({\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\atop1};z\right){_2F_1}\left({\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\atop1};Z\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{4}F_4\left(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2};1,1;z(1-Z),Z(1-z)\right).$$ The Appell function can be written as a double integral on the unit square so that your integral is a triple integral on the unit cube.  Some rearranging of integrals may lead somewhere.

Comment: @DavidH Doesn't [this](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.15.E4) work?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Good to know! I wonder why the MathWorld article fails to mention that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

Our objective is to verify the conjectured identity

$$\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{K{\left(x\right)}K{\left(\sqrt{\frac{2-2x^{2}}{2-x^{2}}}\right)}}{2-x^{2}}=\frac{\pi^{3}}{8\sqrt{2}}\,{_6F_5}{\left(\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\frac34,\frac34,\frac34;\frac12,\frac12,1,1,1;1\right)},\tag{1}$$

where here $K$ denotes the complete elliptic integral of the first kind and is defined via the usual integral representation

$$K{\left(k\right)}:=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-x^{2}\right)\left(1-k^{2}x^{2}\right)}};~~~\small{k\in(-1,1)},$$

and for positive real parameters $\left(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4},a_{5},a_{6}\right)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{6}$ and $\left(b_{1},b_{2},b_{3},b_{4},b_{5}\right)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{5}$ the generalized hypergeometric function ${_6F_5}$ is given by the infinite series

$${_6F_5}{\left(a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4},a_{5},a_{6};b_{1},b_{2},b_{3},b_{4},b_{5};z\right)}:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(a_{1}\right)_{n}\,\left(a_{2}\right)_{n}\,\left(a_{3}\right)_{n}\,\left(a_{4}\right)_{n}\,\left(a_{5}\right)_{n}\,\left(a_{6}\right)_{n}}{\left(b_{1}\right)_{n}\,\left(b_{2}\right)_{n}\,\left(b_{3}\right)_{n}\,\left(b_{4}\right)_{n}\,\left(b_{5}\right)_{n}}\,\frac{z^{n}}{n!},$$

which converges absolutely for $z\in\mathbb{C}\land|z|\le1$ provided that $0<\sum_{j=1}^{5}b_{j}-\sum_{j=1}^{6}a_{j}$.

The Pochhammer symbol $(a)_{n}$ is defined for positive real $a$ and nonnegative integer index $n$ in terms of the gamma function as

$$\left(a\right)_{n}:=\frac{\Gamma{\left(a+n\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(a\right)}};~~~\small{a\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\land n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}}.$$

---

Let $\mathcal{H}$ denote the following generalized hypergeometric series:

$$\mathcal{H}:={_6F_5}{\left(\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\frac34,\frac34,\frac34;\frac12,\frac12,1,1,1;1\right)}.$$

The beta function will be our friend in the evaluation of $\mathcal{H}$:

$$\operatorname{B}{\left(x,y\right)}=\frac{\Gamma{\left(x\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(y\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(x+y\right)}}=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,t^{x-1}\left(1-t\right)^{y-1};~~~\small{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}^{2}}.$$

Consider the following result which allows us to express a certain ratio of Pochhammer symbols as a beta function: for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}$,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\left(\frac14\right)_{n}\,\left(\frac34\right)_{n}}{\left(\frac12\right)_{n}\,\left(1\right)_{n}}
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac12\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(1\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac14+n\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac34+n\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(\frac14\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac34\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac12+n\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(1+n\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac14+n\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac34+n\right)}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac12+n\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(1+n\right)}}\\
&=\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac12\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(2n+\frac12\right)}}{\pi\,\Gamma{\left(2n+1\right)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi}\operatorname{B}{\left(2n+\frac12,\frac12\right)}.\\
\end{align}$$

Then, the hypergeometric series $\mathcal{H}$ can be rewritten as a multiple integral as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}
&={_6F_5}{\left(\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\frac34,\frac34,\frac34;\frac12,\frac12,1,1,1;1\right)}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac14\right)_{n}\,\left(\frac14\right)_{n}\,\left(\frac14\right)_{n}\,\left(\frac34\right)_{n}\,\left(\frac34\right)_{n}\,\left(\frac34\right)_{n}}{\left(\frac12\right)_{n}\,\left(\frac12\right)_{n}\,\left(1\right)_{n}\,\left(1\right)_{n}\,\left(1\right)_{n}}\cdot\frac{1}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\frac14\right)_{n}\,\left(\frac14\right)_{n}\,\left(\frac14\right)_{n}\,\left(\frac34\right)_{n}\,\left(\frac34\right)_{n}\,\left(\frac34\right)_{n}}{\left(\frac12\right)_{n}\,\left(\frac12\right)_{n}\,\left(\frac12\right)_{n}\,\left(1\right)_{n}\,\left(1\right)_{n}\,\left(1\right)_{n}}\cdot\frac{\left(\frac12\right)_{n}}{\Gamma{\left(n+1\right)}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{\left(\frac14\right)_{n}\,\left(\frac34\right)_{n}}{\left(\frac12\right)_{n}\,\left(1\right)_{n}}\right]^{3}\frac{\Gamma{\left(\frac12+n\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(\frac12\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(n+1\right)}}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{\left(\frac14\right)_{n}\,\left(\frac34\right)_{n}}{\left(\frac12\right)_{n}\,\left(1\right)_{n}}\right]^{3}\frac{\Gamma{\left(n+\frac12\right)}\,\Gamma{\left(\frac12\right)}}{\left[\Gamma{\left(\frac12\right)}\right]^{2}\,\Gamma{\left(n+1\right)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi^{4}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[\operatorname{B}{\left(2n+\frac12,\frac12\right)}\right]^{3}\operatorname{B}{\left(n+\frac12,\frac12\right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi^{4}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{t^{2n-1/2}}{\sqrt{1-t}}\,\frac{u^{2n-1/2}}{\sqrt{1-u}}\,\frac{v^{2n-1/2}}{\sqrt{1-v}}\,\frac{w^{n-1/2}}{\sqrt{1-w}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi^{4}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(t^{2}u^{2}v^{2}w\right)^{n}}{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)u\left(1-u\right)v\left(1-v\right)w\left(1-w\right)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi^{4}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{\left(1-t^{2}u^{2}v^{2}w\right)^{-1}}{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)u\left(1-u\right)v\left(1-v\right)w\left(1-w\right)}}.\\
\end{align}$$

It can be shown that

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{1}{\left(1-zw\right)\sqrt{w\left(1-w\right)}}={_2F_1}{\left(1,\frac12;1;z\right)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}};~~~\small{z<1}.$$

Hence,,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{H}
&=\frac{1}{\pi^{4}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{\left(1-t^{2}u^{2}v^{2}w\right)^{-1}}{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)u\left(1-u\right)v\left(1-v\right)w\left(1-w\right)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi^{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)u\left(1-u\right)v\left(1-v\right)}}\\
&~~~~~\times\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}w\,\frac{1}{\left(1-t^{2}u^{2}v^{2}w\right)\sqrt{w\left(1-w\right)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi^{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)u\left(1-u\right)v\left(1-v\right)}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}u^{2}v^{2}}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi^{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)u\left(1-u\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{v\left(1-v\right)\left(1-t^{2}u^{2}v^{2}\right)}}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi^{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)x\left(t-x\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{v\left(1-v\right)\left(1-x^{2}v^{2}\right)}};~~~\small{\left[u=t^{-1}x\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi^{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)x\left(t-x\right)}}\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(x-y\right)y\left(1-y^{2}\right)}};~~~\small{\left[v=x^{-1}y\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi^{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)x\left(t-x\right)}}\\
&~~~~~\times\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}}\int_{0}^{\frac{x}{1+x}}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{u\left(\frac{x}{1+x}-u\right)\left(1-2u\right)}};~~~\small{\left[y=\frac{u}{1-u}\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi^{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)x\left(t-x\right)}}\\
&~~~~~\times\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+x}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-v^{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{2x}{1+x}v^{2}\right)}};~~~\small{\left[u=\frac{x}{1+x}v^{2}\right]}\\
&=\frac{1}{\pi^{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\int_{0}^{t}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{t\left(1-t\right)x\left(t-x\right)}}\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+x}}K{\left(\sqrt{\frac{2x}{1+x}}\right)}\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi^{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{K{\left(\sqrt{\frac{2x}{1+x}}\right)}}{\sqrt{x\left(1+x\right)}}\int_{x}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-t\right)\left(t-x\right)t}}\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi^{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{K{\left(\sqrt{\frac{2x}{1+x}}\right)}}{\sqrt{x\left(1+x\right)}}\int_{0}^{1-x}\mathrm{d}u\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{u\left(1-x-u\right)\left(1-u\right)}};~~~\small{\left[t=1-u\right]}\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi^{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{K{\left(\sqrt{\frac{2x}{1+x}}\right)}}{\sqrt{x\left(1+x\right)}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}v\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1-v^{2}\right)\left(1-(1-x)v^{2}\right)}};~~~\small{\left[u=(1-x)v^{2}\right]}\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi^{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{K{\left(\sqrt{\frac{2x}{1+x}}\right)}K{\left(\sqrt{1-x}\right)}}{\sqrt{x\left(1+x\right)}}\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi^{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{K{\left(\sqrt{\frac{2-2y}{2-y}}\right)}K{\left(\sqrt{y}\right)}}{\sqrt{\left(1-y\right)\left(2-y\right)}};~~~\small{\left[x=1-y\right]}\\
&=\frac{8\sqrt{2}}{\pi^{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\,\frac{K{\left(\sqrt{\frac{2-2y}{2-y}}\right)}K{\left(\sqrt{y}\right)}}{2\left(2-y\right)\sqrt{2\left(\frac{1-y}{2-y}\right)}}\\
&=\frac{8\sqrt{2}}{\pi^{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\,\frac{K{\left(\sqrt{t}\right)}K{\left(\sqrt{\frac{2-2t}{2-t}}\right)}}{2\left(2-t\right)\sqrt{t}};~~~\small{\left[\frac{2-2y}{2-y}=t\right]}\\
&=\frac{8\sqrt{2}}{\pi^{3}}\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\,\frac{K{\left(x\right)}K{\left(\sqrt{\frac{2-2x^{2}}{2-x^{2}}}\right)}}{2-x^{2}};~~~\small{\left[t=x^{2}\right]},\\
\end{align}$$

thus proving the validity of identity $(1)$, so we're done. Cheers!

---

Comment: +1 For a beautiful result.